# cross platform Mobile tracking app to report to custom server?

Tags: gps, android, mobile, ios, tracking

Does any one know of IOS, Andriod apps for asset tracking that I can point to my server?

I can then write some code to intercept the messages from the mobile app.

ideally a solution which works on multiple platforms

I have a tracking web app which current works with dedicated GPS hardware, I now want to add mobile devices to the web app.
instead of developing my own tracking software on every mobile platform, i'm wondering if there are any apps already in existence
I need the mobile app to to send gps tracking positions to a nominated IP address, it can be very simple, and all it will do is send a message to the IP with the Lat and LON every x secs

Is such a thing already out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a closer look at [Miataru](http://miataru.com)

It seems to be an opensource and multi-platform solution,

but I have not tried on my own, so please try to get special information from its website